# Weird Error: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

I have 2 projects,

The first project C# project where I have a blank form(new project).
I am compiling this form as a dll so I can reference the form.

The VB project is an ExcelDNA project which consists of a custom task pane with a button to open the form,the task pane works fine.
However, I get the following error when clicking the Button:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
```

I can get this to work by creating a UserControl in the VB project, and then accessing it via the Button, however I have the form written in C# already and do not want to convert it to VB.

Comment: Well, the DLL has to be accessible by the ExcelDNA project. If this is a regular application, make sure the DLL is copied over to the BIN folder. If this is some kind of Excel add-in, then you may need to have the DLL deployed; having it in the BIN folder won't be enough. PS. Throw a breakpoint in there and check where the current Assembly (use the Reflector namespace) is calling from - that's where your DLL should be.

Comment: Thanks Shamaan,It works, I just needed to copy the C# form dll into the directory where my Excel Add-in was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer to this is to make sure your form Dll is copied to the directory where your Excel Add-In is sitting.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to convert the project to VB.NET. This error is because the .net runtime cannot find the assembly (dll or exe that contains your first form). In Visual Studio, open the `Solution Explorer` window and expand the `References` node. Right-click the reference to your first assembly and click `Properties`. In the properties window change the `Copy Local` as `True`.

This way Visual Studio will copy the assembly to the output folder of the project ('bin\Debug' or 'bin\Release').

Comment: Thanks.. But I did do that already, It seems I just needed to copy the C# form dll into the directory where my Excel Add-in was.

Comment: @Dreamer78692 Well, yes. You need to deploy both assemblies. This means, you need to copy both assemblies to your desired folder.